# Opening www version of my site causes my preferred non-www version to be broken in drupal 7

Tags: seo, drupal-7

I just decided to use drupal 7 for my own site (i'm a newbie here), and i thought that i'd prefer using non-www version ("http://mysite.com") of my site, rather than using the www-version of my site ("http://www.mysite.com").

Everything goes smooth, until i install some modules to be used for SEO purposes :

- Site Verification (requires module token)
- Page Title
- Meta Tags (Quick)
- XML Sitemap

At first glance, everything seems nice and ok. However, when i check my site today (i implemented those SEO module yesterday), just so suddenly, few ugly things happen :

1. The page title is messed up like this : Before messed up : mysite.com | Free website | Free Online Shop | Free web. After messed up : | mysite.com (i have no idea how come it become this way!)
2. Google site verification is missing from the head tag

After some times, i find out that clearing cache through admin - configuration - performance somehow restore it back to the way i set it before (just like the day before). Then i decided to open my site by using "http://www.mysite.com" (i always use "http://mysite.com" before), and suddenly my site goes ugly again (encounter the 2 problem i mentioned above).

My guess is, the google crawler might request a page from my site using "http://www.mysite.com" format, and thus cause my site to goes wrong (the site just got online for few days, i doubt anyone would know its address)

So, could someone please explain to me what's wrong here? I'm totally newbie with drupal 7 and SEO stuffs (just decide to try this thing actually), and maybe solutions to help me overcome this problem?

Thank you for you time, and sorry for the long post.

Regards,

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure out the problem. But I have a solution for this, open .htaccess file and find the following lines (usually, from line #78 to #88)

```
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You can use these lines to force the users to open the website with/without the www. part.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.